# How do I take all the values of a single row under the few id s in PHP Laravel?

Tags: mysql, laravel-5

[image]

This is the output of the select query & I used join query from three tables. How do I take all the values of a single row of id=5 and all of the values of a single row of id=7?

```
$data = DB::table('col3')
       ->join('col2', 'col2.Record_ID', '=', 'col3.Record_ID')
       ->join('col1', 'col1.Record_ID', '=', 'col2.Record_ID') ->select('col1.*', 'col2.*', 'col3.*')
       ->orderBy('col1.Time','desc')         
       ->get();
```

Comment: You mean you want to add a `where` statement?

Comment: Yes, All of the values in id="5" in the first row and all of the values in the id=7 in the first row

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I'm not mistaken, is this not just a case of adding a `where` clause:

```
$data = DB::table('col3')
       ->join('col2', 'col2.Record_ID', '=', 'col3.Record_ID')
       ->join('col1', 'col1.Record_ID', '=', 'col2.Record_ID') ->select('col1.*', 'col2.*', 'col3.*')
       ->whereIn('{table that has the ID e.g col1}.id', [5,7])
       ->orderBy('col1.Time','desc')         
       ->get();
```

Comment: Yes, it's working but received all raw values of the Id ="5" and id="7"..I need to last raw values for 5 and 7. I used ->first() for the where clauses. But not possible.

Comment: Then you need a sub query to do this. Your question isn’t very clear about this.

Comment: I'm trying to get the above table in two raws. In one raw it has id="5" values  according to the latest time & other raw has id="7" values according to the latest time

Comment: If you want to get one row back where it is the latest value then you need to use a subquery to order by the created or updated timestamp and take the first record.